# How to properly apply ternary operator in v-model in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to apply the ternary operator in the v-model but it's not working. I also read a lot of similar questions and answers on StackOverflow but none answer my query.

I have created a data variable **testCondition** which is set to false by default. Using this condition `testCondition?name:place`, **place** is returned in v-model if **testCondition** is false but if **testCondition** is true then v-model does not return anything.

Here is my code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: '',
    place: '',
    testCondition: false,
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: thin solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <br>
  <input type="text" v-model="testCondition?name:place">
  <br><br> Test condition status: {{testCondition}}
  <br> Name: {{name}}
  <br> Place: {{place}}
</div>
```

Expected result: If I change the value of **testCondition** from **false** to **true**, output should be shown in {{name}}

Actual result: Only working for {{place}} if **testCondition** is set to **false**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this: `<input type="text" v-model="$data[testCondition ? 'name' : 'place']">`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: '',
    place: '',
    testCondition: false,
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: thin solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <br>
  <input type="text" v-model="$data[testCondition ? 'name' : 'place']">
  <br><br> Test condition status: {{testCondition}}
  <br> Name: {{name}}
  <br> Place: {{place}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working for this example but, when I try use `$data[testCondition ? 'name' : 'place']` in vue component  where `testCondition` is defined as `prop` I get an error `Avoid adding reactive properties to a Vue instance or its root $data at runtime - declare it upfront in the data option.`

Answer (score 10):

You need a computed property with a getter and a setter: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

```
computed: {
  myModel: {
    get() {
      return this.testCondition ? this.name : this.place;
    }
    set(newValue) {
      this.doSomethingWith(newValue);
    }
}
// then in template: v-model="myModel"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but didn't worked. Also there is a syntax error in your solution.

Comment: @ShubhamPokhriyal Could you please point out the syntax error?